# is it an issue of moving/renaming a folder of asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I would like to rename a folder with asp.net:

```
string oldFolderTitlePath = ServerPhyscialPath + oldFolderTitle + "/";
string newFolderTiltePath = ServerPhyscialPath + newFolderTille+ "/";

DirectoryInfo diPath = new DirectoryInfo(oldFolderTitlePath);

if(diPath.Exists)
{
   ///Now move(Rename) folder on the server         
   Directory.Move(oldFolderTitlePath, newFolderTiltePath);               
}
```

I wonder that if the old folder contains number of files and the size is more than 1GB. Will it take a lot of time to rename a folder on asp.net?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tested it in a test environment yet?  You should be doing that anyway, and it will answer your question for you.

Comment: Strange question. Do you have an issue or are you asking if it could cause an issue(what issue-type do you expect/have?)?

Comment: I've a feeling the application will be recycled when you do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, no it should not take a lot of time.  You're basically changing the name of the directory not actually moving its contents on the disk.

That said, I'd be very careful with doing what you're doing.  I'm always wary of IO operations from ASP.NET -- the reason:  Many users could potentially be executing this code at the same time.  That could lead to all sorts of problems.  You need to make sure this operation is thread safe (perhaps by locking a static variable).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move.aspx